# SQL - Crossing 'Crossed' Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

The title is not good, but it is the way I've found to differentiate my issue from a simple table crossing since my previous researches always get me to these kind of topics.

I have several tables - for simplification, let's name them in only 3: A, B, C. I want to crossing them all in a single table, beeing A the main table.

However, the header in Table B is correlated also with keys in Table C. That is how it looks like my tables:

```
Table A
KEY.1      KEY.2       A.HEADER 
A          NULL         X
B          NULL         X
NULL       AA           X
NULL       BB           X
C          NULL         X
A          NULL         X
NULL       AA           X

Table B
KEY.1      B.HEADER  
A          1           
B          2       
C          3
D          4
E          5
F          6

Table C
KEY.2       KEY.1
AA          D
BB          E
CC          F
```

I want:

```
Final Table
    KEY.1     KEY.2      B.HEADER  A.HEADER
    A         NULL       1         X
    B         NULL       2         X
    D         AA         4         X
    E         BB         5         X
    C         NULL       3         X
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can use a different alias for the joining to the same table again... Say, `b2`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB as b2`.  If your results are wrong, we'll need sample data to help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your example, you want to join on the value in table C when there is no key in table A -- if that's the case then you should be able to join on "whichever one is available" using [the `coalesce` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).  I can't test, but this should get you close:

```
Select , b.header, c.header, a.header
from TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableC as c on (a.key = c.key)
LEFT JOIN TableB as b on (COALESCE(a.key,c.b.key) = b.key)
```

(Order matters with `coalesce` - it'll use the first non-null value it finds, so you may want to flip the order if that's preferable - I dunno whether your table has cases where both values are defined, or what your desired behavior would be...)

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly was able to find a solution for my problem with the help provided here. The query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    coalesce(A.KEY1, C.KEY1) as KEY1,
    A.KEY2,
    B.HEADER,
    A.HEADER
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN C ON (A.KEY2 = C.KEY2)
    LEFT JOIN B ON (coalesce(A.KEY1, C.KEY1) = B.KEY1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you - you just need to provide a different alias for the second join to table B (since it's a different result set):

```
SELECT a.headers, b.headers, BSpecial.specialheader, c.headers, d.headers
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS B on (a.key = b.key)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC AS C on (a.key = c.key)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableD AS D on (a.key = d.key)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS BSpecial on (BSpecial.key = d.key)
```

Comment: It didn't worked. Maybe because BSpecial is also in b.headers. I will update the question...

Comment: What do you mean by 'BSpecial is also in b.headers'?  You can use whatever alias you want.

Comment: Is kind of hard to explain: the thing is that b.header is a part of b.specialheader, but does not have all data. I'm thinking here how can I explain better, please give me a minute.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the CONTENTS of the columns are.  What's important are their names, their types, and what conditions you're using to join them.  Also, when you say "It didn't work" - what happened?  Did you get an error or did you get unexpected results?

Comment: I editted my question to give more examples. Please take a look in my recent update. I thank you in advance for all attention and suport!

Comment: I see you accepted another answer, so I assume you're all set.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Shaw. I wasn't asking well due to my lack of knowledge in SQL. But I manage to solve the problem through AC answer - then I posted what I really used. Thank you for your assistance!